# Display messages in single line in a webpage

Tags: display, using, flash-message

How can I display messages in single line in a webpage using flask? I have tried the following:

```
    lines=sent_tokenize(s)
    sentence_count=len(lines)

    flash("no of sentences :",sentence_count)
```

but the `sentence_count` is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if this is correct, since I'm missing a lot of context, but try below

```
lines=sent_tokenize(s)
sentence_count=len(lines)

flash("no of sentences: %d" % sentence_count)
```

Since `flash` seems to take a string as the first parameter, and `len` returns an integer, put `sentence_count` inside the `"no of sentences"` string

Answer (score 1):

While using python 3.7.6 there are several option to do that

```
"no of sentences: {0}".format(sentence_count)
"no of sentences: {count}".format(count=sentence_count)
"no of sentences: %d" % sentence_count # %d for int, %s for string
f'no of sentences: {sentence_count}'
```